# 16/18 VAC to 5 VDC UPS

Tags: raspberry-pi, ups

I'm new here so please bear with me.

I'm planning to replace my old central alarm system with a new raspberry pi, which takes 5 VDC input.

My old central uses a separate 230 VAC to 16/18 VAC transformer and 12 Volts lead-acid battery as backup.

I'd like to leverage, if possible, the transformer and the battery in order to build a UPS which would feed 5 VDC into the raspberry pi.

Does it make sense to re-use these components? I'd like it to be energy efficient since it would run 24/7. If so, I'd appreciate any help on how to get started.

Thanks,
Juan

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to keep the original batteries, charger and wall wart. This will give you a good 12V rail to work on.

About the 5V rail you can get one of those USB phone chargers for cars, and those should be able to cut it. If you want to roll your own converter go with a [`LM2596-5.0`](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) fixed buck chip.

As a backup plan, you can use a normal phone charger, a USB battery bank and a 5V supercap to power your Pi continuously.

Comment: Thanks. However in my current set-up the battery and the transformer go connected directly to the central unit, which takes care of charging the battery, switching, etc. Once I remove the current central unit all I'll have left is the transformer and the battery, but no charger. I'm struggling to consider if it's worth to leverage those 2 components.

Comment: @JuanCortines You can go for the backup plan and throw away your entire existing stack and go for the phone charger + battery pack stack. Or you may have to roll your own battery charging circuitry. Maybe you can try get one of those commercial UPS that supports external batteries and reuse the battery.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a high efficient buck converter - take wide input option as the battery charger can output voltages even more than 15V.  There are plenty of them on ebay, or an automotive phone charger as suggested by Maxthon Chan - make sure it is not a linear voltage regulator, but buck (step down) DC/DC converter.

Comment: most phone chargers are buck switchers, else they would need to have a large (expensive) heatsink.

Comment: Thanks. However in my current set-up the battery and the transformer go connected directly to the central unit, which takes care of charging the battery, switching, etc. Once I remove the current central unit all I'll have left is the transformer and the battery, but no charger. I'm struggling to consider if it's worth to leverage those 2 components.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine.

- Float charge your battery from the existing charger / PSU.
- Buy a 12 V in, 5 V out 'buck converter' to drop the voltage to the RPi. Go a bit high on the current specification - maybe 1200 mA - so you can power peripherals, if required.

Comment: Thanks. However in my current set-up the battery and the transformer go connected directly to the central unit, which takes care of charging the battery, switching, etc. Once I remove the current central unit all I'll have left is the transformer and the battery, but no charger. I'm struggling to consider if it's worth to leverage those 2 components.